# Logo is not fitting in the specified dimension container in pdf using apache velocity template

Tags: html, css, velocity, web-frontend

```
#macro(logoLiveAreaSection)
<fo:block-container width="52mm" height="18mm" position="relative">
  <fo:block position="absolute" top="0" left="0">
    $liveArea.render("logo_live_area")
   </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
#end
```

I am trying to fit the new logo in container in pdf but it is coming out of that specified size, it should be fit within (52x18)mm space
Any suggestion, What should be done to solve it?
I am using this code
I tried using overflow property but no luck

Comment: Solution tried:

<fo:block-container overflow="auto" clip="auto" width="52mm" height="18mm" position="relative">
    <fo:block position="absolute" top="50" left="50">
        <fo:external-graphic scaling="non-uniform" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/>
        $liveArea.renderImageFopBuilder("logo_live_area")
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>

Answer (score 0):

another way to insert logo is to set a variable and specify your file

```
#set ($logo1Url="url('file:/data/logos/yourlogo.png')")
```

And you can use your variable in the code below

```html
<fo:inline >
  <fo:external-graphic src="$logo1Url" content-height="64px" content-width="64px"/>
</fo:inline>
```

**external-graphic** is used for a graphic where the graphics data resides outside of the XML result tree.
To specify size, use **content-height** and **content-width**.
Documentation is available [here](https://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/xslfo_reference.asp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked.

```
#set($logoliveArea = $liveArea.renderLogoImageFopBuilder("logo_live_area"))
 
<fo:external-graphic scaling="uniform" width="52mm" height="18mm" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="scale-to-fit" overflow="hidden" src="$logoliveArea"/>
```